# Repeat control onClick navigate to mobile page

Tags: mobile, xpages, lotus-notes

Instead of a view I have a repeat control with checkboxes on mobile page 1. I want to be able to navigate to another mobile page (Details page) by clicking on that checkbox label. So how do I do that? Is there a way to turn repeat control row into navigation item (so it shows an right arros). On that another mobile page I want to show details about clicked item in repeat. Assume I can use scope variables. But how do I actually navigate? Here is my simple mobile app page:

```
<xe:singlePageApp id="singlePageApp1" selectedPageName="mLists">
    <xe:appPage id="appPage1" pageName="mLists">
        <xe:djxmHeading id="djxmHeading1" label="*** app name ***">
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xp:button value="Submit" id="button1" xp:key="actionFacet"></xp:button>
            </xp:this.facets>
        </xe:djxmHeading>
    <xp:panel id="panelMain">
        <xp:repeat id="repeatList" rows="10000" var="rowData"
            indexVar="rowDataIndex" repeatControls="true" value="#{viewScope.LIST_REPEAT}">
                <xp:checkBox id="lstCheckBox_${rowDataIndex}">
                    <xp:this.text><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowData[1]}]]></xp:this.text>
                </xp:checkBox>
                <xp:br></xp:br>
        </xp:repeat>
    </xp:panel>
    </xe:appPage>
    <xe:appPage id="appPage2" pageName="mDetails" resetContent="true">
        <xe:djxmHeading id="djxmHeading2" label="DETAILS" back="Back" moveTo="mLists" transition="slide">
        </xe:djxmHeading>
        <xe:djxmRoundRectList id="djxmRoundRectList1">
            <xp:panel></xp:panel>
        </xe:djxmRoundRectList>
    </xe:appPage>
</xe:singlePageApp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Simple Actions for moving between pages inside mobile controls. Here's an example on an image.

```
<xp:image url="/63_48x48.png" id="image3" styleClass="imageLeft">
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                        refreshMode="complete" id="eventHandler2">
                        <xp:this.action>
                            <xe:moveTo direction="Left to Right"
                                targetPage="manifests" forceFullRefresh="false"
                                transitionType="slide">
                            </xe:moveTo>
                        </xp:this.action>
                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:image>
```

I highly recommend you abandon all use of Mobile Controls inside XPages.  I've talked about this off an on over at NotesIn9. Sadly it's just not a safe way to build applications.

To better flesh out the "Don't use Mobile Controls" statement.  Here's a link to several blog posts I made when iOS8 came out.

http://www.notesin9.com/?s=ios8

Here's the skinny : iOS8 came out and broke Mobile Controls. It could EASILY happen again.

What are "Mobile Controls"?  They're pieces of the dojo javaScript framework.  The break was caused by a change in iOS Safari I think.  Dojo did put a fix in but then what?  We couldn't easily absorb the fix.  We needed to wait for IBM to release a fixpack with the newer version of Dojo. It couldn't be delivered via the Ext. Library unfortunately. IBM did get a fix out very quickly for them but for the users was a problem for several weeks. And that fixpack was unprecedented I believe.  So it could have gone much longer.

More recently Chrome caused something to break in how dojo allows XPages to do the Partial Refresh.  Within 10 days or so Chrome did correct their change and pushed out an update.

Dojo, different browsers, different os's. At any point 1 of them might break another. There's so many moving parts. The core risk here with Mobile Controls is that in this situation IBM just can not get a fix out in a manner that's timely to a user.

Note I've not even mentioned that Mobile Controls, even if there was no risk, just don't scale well to bigger apps. If it's not simple just don't do it.  Also while IBM has said they still support them, I believe they've said that they won't be enhancing them and recommend the Bootstrap option going forward.

It's much better to use a framework you have more control of.  They can update Bootstrap much faster because it's in the Ext. Library.  You could even manually use your own version of Bootstrap if necessary.  So it's just a safer play.

Why listen to me?
I did many videos (NotesIn9.com / XPages.TV) and presentations on teaching people how to use Mobile Controls.  I did a big app in the Day Job using Mobile Controls.  I'll never use them again for anything and recommend you don't either.

Comment: I've not understood your point.. Don't use Mobile Controls or don't use xPages for mobile devices? What else to use instead of Single Page Application and Mobile Page controls? Do you mean to use just regular control but adjust its size to mobile?

Comment: Bootstrap responsive is the recommended approach now. That's been available for over a year now in OpenNTF release of Extension Library so has become mature now

Comment: XPages work great for mobile apps.  They're just webpages.  Bootstrap is the recommended starter solution.  I'll add more information to my answer regarding mobile controls.  I didn't mean to be flip.  But Mobile Controls should no longer be used with XPages in my opinion.  Recommend using bootstrap from the latest ext. library.